# What is the query of SAS

Tags: sas

What is this SAS query doing?

```
Data calss;
Set (existing data);
Run;
```

If you have any answer please help me. And you can tell the source, from where we can practice of query.

Comment: https://www.sas.com/en_ca/software/on-demand-for-academics.html You can set up a free account here.

Answer (score 1):

We call this a data step. It is rather a program than a query.

In this

```
Data WORK.CLASS;
Set SASHELP.CLASS;
Run;
```

With `Data WORK.CLASS;`, you say the program should make a table CLASS in your WORK library. Libraries are somewhat simular to Db2 schemas; The WORK library is automatically created when you start a SAS session and deleted when you close it.

With `Set SASHELP.CLASS;`, you say it should read all rows from the CLASS table in the SASHELP library. The SASHELP library is always there. It contains system tables (comparable to the system tables of Db2) and example data that you can use to excersise.

`Run;` starts compilation and execution